# chartjs not following height when parent's height is 200px

Tags: chart.js, vue-chartjs

Im using vue-chartjs to display a doughnut chart. I want the chart to follow the parent's height(200px).

I tried to set `maintainAspectRatio` to false in the option, it shrinked, but still not fit into the parent div.

This is the option I'm using for the chart.

```
import { Pie } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Pie,
  name: 'Pie_Chart',
  props: ["rating"],
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart({
      legend: { display: false },
      datasets: [{
        backgroundColor: ['#DAE02A', '#6D6D6D'],
        data: [1000, this.$props.rating],
        borderWidth: 0
      }]
    }, {
      responsive:true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      cutoutPercentage: 80,
      legend: { display: false },
      tooltips: { enabled: false },
      hover: { mode: false },
    })
  },
}
```

Although the width of the chart has fit into the parent div, but there are still some empty space above and below the chart which causes the height to not fit into the parent div.

#### working sample of my problem

*before adding maintainAspectRatio*
[image: before adding maintainAspectRatio]
*after adding maintainAspectRatio*
[image: after adding maintainAspectRatio]
*after setting width of parent*
[image: after setting width of parent]
*generated html*
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't provided a [working example of your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it can't be directly solved.

The result you want is possible, so here's a snippet showing a doughnut chart sized to exactly 200px by 200px (I've added a `background-color` to the `div` for clarity):

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "doughnut",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [1, 4]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    cutoutPercentage: 80,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    },
    hover: {
      mode: false
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #ccf;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: i had added some working example of my problem, after seeing your answer, i went to set the width of the parent div and finally the chart has the size i want, but they are still some spaces above and below the chart (just like in the third image), do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: @TeeVeeHan Try setting `position:relative` on the parent `div`. It looks like chartjs is overflowing the container.

Comment: still the same.

Comment: chartjs automatically set the height of the canvas to 400

Comment: @TeeVanHan The only other idea I have is to set `overflow:hidden` on the parent `div`. If that doesn't work you'll need to add some code to your question as otherwise I'm just guessing what the problem could be.

Comment: only upper half of the chart is visible after i use `overflow:hidden`. I included the whole script for generating the chart in the post. i also attached the html block generated by vue-chartjs as the 4th image.

Comment: Oddly, i managed to solve this problem by removing `maintainAspectRatio: false`. Anyway, thanks for helping.